# ava.net.ConnectException: Tried all: '1' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server: , port: '80'

Tags: java, web-services, https, wsdl, connectionexception

I am obtaining the below exception while consuming a web service:

HTTP transport error: java.net.ConnectException: Tried all: '1' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server: 'abc.def.ghi.com', port: '80'

I check the wsdl and it has a following lines at the end:

```
<wsdl:port name="PaymentServiceImplPort" binding="tns:PaymentServiceImplSoapBinding"> 
    <soap:address location="http://abc.def.ghi.com:80/pciws/IPaymentService"/> 
</wsdl:port>
```

Even though we are trying to consume the webservice over https, it tries to access the webservice via port 80 only. 
The port 80 is disabled on the webserver and hence it is throwing the exception.

Any pointers in solving the exception will be appreciated.

Comment: Get the WSDL to use the proper location, then?

Comment: So you mean edit the wsdl and pass the wsdl to proper location ?
Also once i do that , how can i be sure it is accessing the proper port.

Comment: Also i am not sure how this wsdl is generated for port 80.